# Higher dimension derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differentiation, spacetime-dimensions

In the case of higher dimensions (e.g. 4+1 dimensions) how would the 5 derivative ($\partial_5$) change?

For example if $\\X=(x^{\mu},z)$, would the 5 derivative change as $$\partial_5\partial^5X=\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}x+\partial_{z}d^zz$$ or $$\partial_5\partial^5X=\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}x-\partial_{z}d^zz$$

Comment: I don't understand how $\partial_5$ and $\partial_z$ are supposed to denote different objects - isn't $z$ supposed to be the fifth coordinate here? Is one of these supposed to be the derivative w.r.t. the fifth coordinate and the other a generic index?

Comment: Metric is what I am referring to, I realise that I wasn't clear, what I was basically asking is since $\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}X=\partial_t \partial^t-\nabla^2 X$, if there were a fifth dimension, would the 5th dimension also be minus like $\nabla$ or positive? ie does $\partial_{\mu_5} \partial^{\mu_5}X= \partial_t \partial^t X-\nabla^2 X-\partial_z \partial^z X$

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on how you contract the indices, which means, on how you are applying it, but neither of what you wrote makes much sense, some possibilities would be ($\mu_5$ is gonna be an index of 5 dim which I'm gonna separate into $\mu_4$ for the first 4 dim and $z$ for the last) :
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu_5} X^{\mu_5}= \partial_{\mu_4} X^{\mu_4}+\partial_{z} X^{z}
\end{equation}
or:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu_5} \partial^{\mu_5} A= \partial_{\mu_4} \partial^{\mu_4} A+\partial_{z} \partial^{z}A
\end{equation}
So if your question is purely on the sign, you have to keep always in mind, that Einstein notation implies a **SUM** for contracted indices, no subtraction there ever, the subtraction appears when you start changing the expression with metrics.

Some examples to make myself more clear:
\begin{equation}
X_{\mu_5}X^{\mu_5}=X_{\mu_4}X^{\mu_4}+X_{z}X^{z} = g^{\mu_4\mu_4}X_{\mu_4}X_{\mu_4}+g^{zz}X_{z}X_{z}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_{\mu_5}X_{\mu_5}=X_{\mu_4}X_{\mu_4}+X_{z}X_{z} = g_{\mu_4\mu_4}X_{\mu_4}X^{\mu_4}+g_{zz}X_{z}X^{z}
\end{equation}
so when the indices don't change position (up/down) it's always a **SUM**! :)

Comment: Metric is what I am referring to, I realise that I wasn't clear, what I was basically asking is since $\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}X=\partial_t \partial^t-\nabla^2 X$, if there were a fifth dimension, would the 5th dimension also be minus like $\nabla$ or positive? ie does $\partial_{\mu_5} \partial^{\mu_5}X= \partial_t \partial^t X-\nabla^2 X-\partial_z \partial^z X$

Comment: Well you can have what ever that space  will have in reality space-time is curved so the metric and derivatives are more complex than what you wrote already.

Comment: But I'll try to answer using your "words", if the added dimension was an extra time dimension it would be with + and if it was a space dimension a -. But as I said not even the normal 4D  are really + or -.